# why does my non dairy creamer not dissolve in coffee?

Tags: substitutions, coffee, milk

I use Nestle's Everyday Whitener to make coffee. But with some brands of coffee (eg: Davidoff) the creamer doesn't seem to dissolve. It instead remains suspended as granules in the coffee.
But with other Nescafe brands of coffee the dissolution occurs easily.
What's the difference and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the contents of the coffee and the creamer and how they react to each other. For example some creamers are just corn syrup solids mixed with emulsifiers, and they usually mix less effectively if the coffee isn't hot enough.

Or, as you mentioned, if the problem is with the brand of the coffee, then it's possible that the coffee that's giving you trouble contains more oil than the other.

If you've soaked oily dishes in detergent, sometimes if there's enough oil, once the water cools down, there will be bits of solid oil floating on the surface. It's basically the same with your coffee. The warmer the temperature and the less oil, makes a better mix.

That said, I prefer using milk if you can. If you're lactose intolerant or allergic to milk fats, I'd suggest substitutes like soy, rice, or almond milks. The closest I've found is half almond, half coconut milk. Or better still, just drink it black.

Comment: Heloo lzl. Welcome to Seasoned Advice! I've proposed an edit to your answer that removes the health claims as that type of content is off topic here. We are a community of amateur and professional cooks who try to give expert cooking advice. We leave health and nutrition up to experts in those areas.

Comment: ok, that's cool.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that my non-dairy creamer dissolves just fine, unless... I dissolve the saccharin-based sweetener first.  If I put the saccharin-based sweetener in first, the non-dairy creamer makes lots of clumps and doesn't dissolve properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use half and half. More on the actual question though q: it may help to dissolve in just a bit of water first so it's easier to really mash it in and get it all wet. Just a theory though!

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean with the non dissolving creamer. Normally though, I find it happens when the water isnt hot enough. Maybe just check that it is and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Your whitener may have the same problem as when I use soy milk in my coffee. With certain brands of coffee the milk curdles due to the acidity of the coffee. I have found that the curdling is also influenced by the temperature difference between the milk and the coffee.

For this reason I suggest:

Buying coffee that you know is not too acidic for your whitener or at least heating the whitener before mixing it with the coffee.